# How to add jitter in a data frame in R

Tags: r, jitter

Input:

```
df = data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 5:9)
rownames(df) <- letters[1:5]


#add jitter
jitter(df) #Error in jitter(df) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Expected output: jitter will be added to the columns of `df`. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`jitter` is a function that takes `numeric` as input. You cannot simply run `jitter` on the whole `data.frame`. You need to loop through the columns. You can do:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, jitter))
```

Comment: would you know how to exclude `jitter` on missing or `NA` values? I'm trying to avoid removing rows with any missing or `NA` values (e.g. `df[complete.cases(df), ]`).

Answer (score 4):

`Jitter` is to be applied to a numerical vector, not a dataframe.
If you want to apply Jitter to all your columns, this should do:

```
apply(df, 2, jitter)
```

Comment: This is unsafe. Don't use `apply()` on a dataframe unless you want to coerce it to a to matrix where all columns are of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding random numbers?

```
df_jit <- df + matrix(rnorm(nrow(df) * ncol(df), sd = 0.1), ncol = ncol(df))
```